# MATLAB: How to locate a data mixed with number and string?

Tags: string, matlab

The data is imported as .mat from .csv by using xlsread, and looks like this:

0203.ENG

0412.DXY

....

How to return the row and column of '0412.DXY'?

Thanks!

Comment: There isn't enough information in this question to answer the file. Matlab doesn't store items in a row/col format that include letters, so I don't know where you are getting that from. We would need to know the type of data storage. Try opening a clean Matlab window, loading the function, and using the `whos` command, posting the output here, and letting us know what value you want to get.

Comment: It does store the combination...by using xlsread

Comment: @user1205030: Please include more details in the question, like things were coming from an xlsread operation. This kind of detail is important, and can't be solved otherwise.

Comment: I am sorry!! detail added. : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've got a cell array reading raw data by XLSREAD.

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename);
```

Then you can find row and column of a particular string with

```
[r, c] = find(strcmp(raw,'0412.DXY'));
```